# Why is encrypt() returning None?

Tags: python

I know it's a little gutsy to ask for a bunch of people to look through several blocks of code but I will try anyway. I am trying to create a clone of the enigma (the German encryption machine used in world war two) in python with tk. Looking through my code logically,the method `encrypt()` is either returning the string "Alert", which is highly unlikely, or it is returning `None`. Would someone please give it a quick but dedicated glance so I can fix this? Thank you.

```
from Tkinter import *
from string import letters
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.title("EnigmaTK")

def rank(x, d = dict((letr,n%26+1) for n,letr in enumerate(letters[0:52]))):
    return d[x]


def shift(key, array):
    counter = range(len(array))
    new = counter
    for i in counter:
        new[i] = array[i-key]
    return new

alph = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "]
rotI = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "]
rotII = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "]
rotIII = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "]
ref = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "e", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "]

label = Label(root, text="Input:")
label.pack(side = LEFT)
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack(side = RIGHT)
input = entry.get()
rotor_set = map(rank, input[:3])
message = input[3:]


def encrypt():
    new_message = message
    for a in xrange(len(message)):
        for e in range(rotor_set[2]):
            new_message[a] = alph[rotI.index(rotII[rotIII.index(ref[rotIII.index(rotII[rotI.index(alph[a])])])])]
            a = a + 1
            rotIII = shift(1, rotIII)
        for i in range(rotor_set[1]):
            new_message[a] = alph[rotI.index(rotII[rotIII.index(ref[rotIII.index(rotII[rotI.index(alph[a])])])])]
            a = a + 1
            rotII = shift(1, rotII)
        for o in range(rotor_set[0]):
            new_message[a] = alph[rotI.index(rotII[rotIII.index(ref[rotIII.index(rotII[rotI.index(alph[a])])])])]
            a = a + 1
            rotI = shift(1, rotI)
    return new_message


def show():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "English to Enigma", encrypt())


e = Button(root, text = "encrypt", command = show)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The alphabets near the top are all the same. I will change this if the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `encrypt` is throwing an exception that is translated to an alert by Tk. You might be able to see the exception if you start the program from a command-line.

If it is an exception, my guess would be that you are trying to modify `new_message` by doing `new_message[a] = ...`. If `new_message` is a string (or tuple), this is not allowed in Python as strings are immutable. Instead, use a list:

```
new_message = list(message)
```

and join the message when you return:

```
return ''.join(new_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be executed at the wrong time:

```
input = entry.get()
```

I presume you want to fetch the data when the user clicks the button, not at the beginning of your program run. Since you don't fetch the data when the use clicks the button, `message` remains an empty string, `new_message` becomes an empty string, and `encrypt()` returns an empty string.

A possible solution is to modify `encrypt()`:

```
def encrypt():
    input = entry.get()
    new_message = input[3:]
    ...
```